# Using SQLite or MS Access, how should the tables be organized to model the logic of this 3D structure?

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, sqlite, normalization

[Here is an explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emotions#Plutchik.27s_wheel_of_emotions) of how the elements are related.

tl;dr: Intensity is strongest at the center of the diagram.  The basic emotions (in the arms) combine to form secondary emotions in the outer circle. (i.e., Anticipation + Joy = Optimism)

What is the best way to design a database to model this set of relationships?

[Plutchick's Wheel of Emotions http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Plutchik%27s_Wheel_of_Emotions.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Plutchik%27s_Wheel_of_Emotions.png)

Comment: Honestly, it depends on how you're going to use it.  Is this going to be used to classify mood?  Or just for display-only purposes?  If so, you can use a single lookup table for the 8 leaves, another for intensity, and then a 3rd that combines the two.  But I suspect you want to use it for something more indepth.

Comment: Looks a little bit like student's homework.

Comment: In a course on ER modeling or relational databases, I suspect.

Comment: It's not homework, it's work-work.  I thought that this might make a good model for categorizing a large music library (based on the emotive content of the songs being tracked) - but only if I could design the db properly in the first place.  I'm not sure if a relational database is the really the right approach - but I don't know the first thing about multidimensional databases.

Comment: @sealclubber: sorry that I suspected homework, but really, it helps people to understand your questions better if you tell them a little bit about the context you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you need a table `Emotion`. Should have at least a primary key `ID` and an attribute `Name` (better `Emotionname`, since Name is often a reserved word). Perhaps you will need some additional boolean attributes for categorizing it ("Simple", "Pure", and so on), an intensity attribute. If you need the colors, you can also add a `ColorCode` attribute.

Then, depending on your use cases, you should add some recursive relations to that table, for example an `OppositeEmotionID` foreign key or two keys `ComposedByEmotion1ID`, `ComposedByEmotion2ID`. Just add only those relations you are really going to use.